# Blocking 3rd-party image in Android browser?

Tags: browser, images

For Firefox 4 for Windows, there is a really useful image-block addon for slow connections: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/quickimage/

Unfortunately, Firefox mobile is pretty slow and the addon doesn't exist for it. Most browsers can turn off image loading in options/settings. But often this causes a horrible site look. Blocking only 3rd-party image sources really makes browsing on 64kB/s mobile connections a lot faster. Generally, you don't need things like Opera Turbo Mode, it's not like DSL speed, but sites load within 5-10 sec.

So is there a way to block 3rd-party images by default? Tools like AdBlock don't show images with distinct paths (, but download all images by default?). I'm not looking for something like Opera Mini or Opera Mobile Turbo mode. I know these options.

---

**I found a solution for Firefox (built-in config setting). I keep the question open, as someone may find to do the same thing on Dolphin HD or Opera**. Then Dolphin would become my standard mobile browser.

Comment: So you don't want to block all images on a webpage, just 3rd party images, i.e. adds?

Comment: @chance test the quickimage desktop firefox add-on or try my answer below. I'm aware of adblock, but this is much better for low bandwidth cell phone contracts

Answer (score 1):

Found out that **Firefox mobile** can do this by going to

```
about:config
```

in address bar and setting

```
permissions.default.images         3
```

Possible values:

- `1` = load all images
- `2` = no images
- `3` = only images from the current URL

Saves a lot of bandwidth (e.g. user avatars on Stack Exchange are not loaded, while with "no image loading", one doesn't see voting arrows). I just don't like mobile views of sites that much. An add-on would be nice to easily switch this config setting for a single website like the *quick image* addon on Firefox Desktop.

If Dolphin HD had this, feature it would be unbeatable. Unfortunately, Firefox is lacking the speed and tap gestures of Dolphin.