# Firefox for Android: blocking images?

Tags: firefox-for-android, data-plan, bandwidth

I would like to prevent Firefox from loading images, due to 3g data limit.

- I was googling for an anwser, but it seems that option is not available, and, to my surprise, I did not find any posts mentioning it *does not* exist.
- There is no option in `about:config` that looks like the one `permissions.default.image` in the desktop version of Firefox.
- No extension (in particular, the [Image Block](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-block/)) seems to be installable in Firefox 16.0 for Android.

Can you suggest a solution, or a browser, which supports this feature?

Comment: Possibly related/dupe: [Blocking 3rd-party image in Android browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/11702/44325)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Dolphin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsIm1vYmkubWdlZWsuVHVubnlCcm93c2VyIl0.) browser has an option to turn off images.  I believe most versions of the stock browser have this capability as well.  The 4.0.4 version can disable images via `Settings ->Bandwidth management -> Load images`, and I'm pretty sure that the Gingerbread browser had this capability as well.

Comment: Yes, the gingerbread stock browser has this; I just checked. Under `Settings`->`Load Images`.

Answer (score 1):

[Opera Mini / Opera Mobile](http://www.opera.com/mobile/specs/) are two recommended options for saving money on data charges:

> Opera's mobile browsers are the smart choice for browsing on expensive
>   wireless data plans. Using Opera Mini or Opera Mobile to browse the
>   web with your mobile phone can save you money on your phone bills, by
>   reducing your data usage substantially. Opera Mini uses only a tenth
>   of the bandwidth of other browsers, compressing webpages by up to 90%.
>   With Opera Mobile, turning on Opera Turbo compresses data by up to
>   80%, or leave Opera Turbo off to get full website data, as you would
>   on a PC.

[image: Data compression in Opera mobile browsers]

Additionaly, of course, they allow to turn off images via settings.

You can download them from

- http://www.opera.com/mobile/download/
- http://m.opera.com

Comment: Thanks. I don't like opera for political reasons (closed-source) though.

Comment: OK, I can't fight against that, but I won't delete my answer just in case someone else have the same problem and he/she finds useful this alternative.

Comment: It was not meant as offense, sorry for misunderstanding. Your answer is technically very valid and definitely worth keeping here.

Comment: Don't worry: I didn't take it as offense :)

Answer (score 1):

At Firefox Android Add-Ons, there is a recent add-on that is just what you want:

## [Mobile Image Blocker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/android/addon/mobile-image-blocker/) v1.0

> Speed up browsing on mobile connections and use less data by blocking all images. Working on images defined in HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

[image: ADD-ONS Page Screenshot]

Comment: This answer could be a lot more useful if you added a link to the add-on.

Answer (score 1):

Try the add-on uBlock and tick Block media elements larger than...(I set mine to 1KB)

Answer (score 0):

this feature is now available in [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/) but will be shipped in 45/46: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1170725

Menu->Settings->Advanced->Show Images

Answer (score 0):

If you always want Firefox to block images when using mobile data then you can [set it in the menu](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-or-load-images-over-wifi-firefox-android): *Settings* → *Advanced* → *Show images* → choose *Only over Wi-Fi* or *Blocked*. This is however tedious if you often quickly want to turn this option on or off.

As far as I know, there‘s no working add-on for Firefox for Android (Fennec) 67.0 at the moment (the mentioned addon Mobile Image Blocker is not compatible anymore since quite some time).

However, there‘s **[Firefox Lite](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox-lite)** as an leightweight browser app for Android (seems like it was called Firefox Rocket formerly). Apparently it‘s currently only available in some asian countries through Google Play, but you can also install it via [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) from anywhere in the world (either install F-Droid or manually download an install the Firefox Lite APK file [from the F-Droid website](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.mozilla.rocket/)).
It has an easily accessible option for enabling and disabling blocking images. In the current state it‘s lacking some features like linking it to Firefox Sync for syncing bookmarks for example. Overall it‘s still a good option to reduce traffic when surfing the web on the go.